# RestAssured: verify creation of entity

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

Im posting simple data like

```
{
"title" : "test Title"
}
```

to (let it be) /posts uri, eg smth like

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost";
        RestAssured.basePath = "/posts";
        given()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .body("{\n" +
                        "    \"title\": \"test Title\"\n" +
                        "}")
                .when()
                .post("")
                .then().statusCode(201)
                // .and(Verify that post created);
    }
```

I can verify, that body is not null with

```
.body(notNullValue())
```

or check, that field in response has value we are setting, like

```
.body("title", equalTo("test Title"))
```

But im not sure, its optimal/correct way.
So, question: how to verify, that entity was created, after posting, with restAssured?

Comment: Hi, it all depends on server side implementation -it could do nothing and return a 200. If this is for test, why not do a 'get' to verify if entity was created.

Comment: yes, its for test, and with get seems to be easyway. Just wondering, how to do this in the borders of one request (post) and thats it.

Comment: Since code executes on the server side, no way client would know if it really did its job - what  was expected, there has a to be a query to DB for example to verify, or a list/get call to verify - as if create code failed, it would not fetch the entity being requested to be created. I can create a server APi which accepts a POST/create request, and in code just return a response entity with whatever status I like.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the response content to make sure it's correct using jsonPath. Below response for a get request , but you can use it with some amendments

```
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

    Response response=given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).get("http://localhost:3000/posts");
              //we need to convert response as a String and give array index
            JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response.asString());
            String title = jsonPath.getString("title");
    // use index if response returns an array
            String author=jsonPath.getString("author[2]");
            // if it's int 
            int user_id = jsonPath.getInt("user_id");
            System.out.println("title is "+title+" customerName is "+author);
```